# Tmdb Json Array Decode

Tags: php, arrays, json, var-dump, themoviedb-api

I can't get *tmdb* movies ID, because this array is actually an *array in array*.

So I can't get it even if I tried many different solutions. I will be grateful if you could help me.

```
<?php
$tmdb_json = file_get_contents('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=05902896074695709d7763505bb88b4d&language=en-US&page=1');

$tmdb = array();
$tmdb = json_decode($tmdb_json, true);
//$json_filex = substr($tmdb_json, 61,-2);

var_dump($tmdb);
?>
```

Comment: This code works as expected, what is the issue?

Comment: I corrected some grammar typos and some formatting, but OP needs to be more clear about what is the issue (expected behavior vs. Actual behavior) and about the solutions they already tried.